# Does every commutative $*$-algebra of operators on a prehilbert space have a character?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, real-algebraic-geometry, unitary-representations

My question can be equivalently stated as follows:

> Let $A$ be a complex commutative algebra with involution, and assume there exists a non-zero homomorphism $\pi:A\to L(V)$ to the algebra of linear operators on a pre-hilbert space $V$ (a.k.a. $*$-representation) such that $\langle\pi(a)v,w\rangle=\langle v,\pi(a^*)w\rangle$ for all $a\in A,\ v,w\in V.$ Does there exist a non-zero $*$-homomorphism $\varphi:A\to\mathbb C\ ?$

In case when $V$ is a Hilbert space the answer is yes. All operators $\pi(a)$ are bounded, hence $\overline{\pi(A)}$ is a commutative $C^*$-algebra which has a character.

If $A$ is finitely generated, the answer is also yes. It follows from the property $$\forall f_i\in A:\ \ \ \sum_{i=1}^k f_i^*f_i=0\ \ \ \mbox{implies}\ \ \ f_1=\dots=f_k=0.$$

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this. Do we know that there are such $A$ which are not pre-C*-algebras?

Comment: @Christian: that's an interesting example, but with appropriate norm your $A$ is a pre-C*-algebra. Of course my question was imprecise. Let's ask this: if $V$ is a pre-Hilbert space and $A$ is a self-adjoint commutative $*$-algebra of linear operators on $V$ (possibly unbounded, with involution in the OP's sense), then is there a norm on $A$ which makes it a pre-C*-algebra? Relevant because a positive answer would answer OP's question. So do we know the answer is negative?

Comment: @NikWeaver: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood, we need specifically $\|f\|_A=\|\widehat{f}\|_{\ell^1}$.

Comment: @NikWeaver: Still not answering your question as posed, but here's another example: the matrices $( \begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{smallmatrix})$ with involution "complex conjugate" form an algebra that satisfies the OP's conditions (and has one complex homomorphism), but there is no norm that makes $A$ a $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: @Christian: I don't understand, involution is entrywise complex conjugate? Does this satisfy $\langle Av,w\rangle = \langle v, A^*w\rangle$?

Comment: @NikWeaver: Yes, this is the involution. But my $A$ is as in the OP (just a commutative $*$-algebra), it's not a subalgebra of $L(V)$ (that's why it doesn't answer your question); it does act on $V=\mathbb C$ by multiplication by $a$.

Comment: @NikWeaver: I believe that my problem has a positive solution and, moreover, I think such $A$ has a separating family of characters with locally-compact weak topology. Taking supremum over this set we would get a $C^*$-norm on $A$.

Comment: @Yurii, please post details when you're ready. Sounds interesting.